# Неверный ответ с COM-порта при использовании USB-COM (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, com-порт

При попытке чтения ответа с COM-порта при использовании переходника USB-COM получается считать либо мусор(непонятные значения байтов и не то их число, которое необходимо), либо вообще ничего.
При запуске данной программы на ПК со встроенным COM-портом такого не встречается.

Может кто знает в чем проблема и как ее можно исправить/обойти?

Прикладываю код для наглядности:

```
ser = serial.Serial(self.com_port_name)
ser.baudrate = 57600
ser.timeout = 2
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.xonxoff=False
ser.rtscts=False
ser.dsrdtr=False
```

Запись:

```
buf = bytearray([0, 0, 0, 0])
buf[0] = COM_WRITE
buf[1] = value
buf[2] = value + 1
buf[3] = (2 * buf[1] + buf[0] + 1) & 0xFF
ser.write(buf)
```

Чтение:

```
raw = bytearray([0, 0, 0, 0])
while not ser.in_waiting:
    time.sleep(0.01)
raw = ser.read(4)

if  len(raw) == 4:
    if(raw[0] != 0xD6):
        print("Неверный код ответа!")
        return 1
    if (raw[1] != value):
        print("Установлено неверное значение аттенюатора!")
        return 1
    if (raw[3] != (2 * raw[1] + raw[0] + 1) & 0xFF):
        print("В ответе неверная контрольная сумма!")
        return 1
```

Comment: В прошлой ветке я вам советовал контролировать обмен. Пробовали? А штатную программу? А с заглушкой (перемкнуть 2-3 контакты) на данном переходнике? И рассчитывать на то, что вся посылка придёт одной пачкой в 4 байта - не стоит.

Comment: сначала перемычкой и проверить эхо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сменить адаптер USB-COM. Некоторые из них весьма кривые. А так же у них могут быть весьма кривые драйверы. Сам я работал с таким адаптером из-под C++ и проблем не было. Ниже ссылка на тот адаптер. Фирма-производитель STLab.

https://fcenter.ru/product/goods/96314-Perehodnik_USB2_0_4xCOM_9M_STLab_U_400

UPD1:

Если Вы работаете под виндой, то еще может быть что порты адаптера устанавливаются в системе с номерами больше 10. А если COM порты в винде имеют номер номерами больше 10, то их надо открывать по-хитрому, сейчас точно не помню но вроде со слэшем перед именем. Может быть Python в винде не понимает портов с номером больше 10.

UPD2:

> у меня открывало без слеша

Поглядел, как надо открывать COM порты с номером большим, чем 9. Вот что написано:

> Указатель на строку с именем открываемого или создаваемого файла.
>   Формат этой строки может быть очень «хитрым». В частности можно
>   указывать сетевые имена для доступа к файлам на других компьютерах.
>   Можно открывать логические разделы или физические диски и работать в
>   обход файловой системы.
>
> Последовательные порты имеют имена "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4",
>   "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9". Для доступа к портам, чей
>   номер больше 9, необходимо указывать имя порта как "\.\COMx", где x -
>   номер порта. Например, "\.\COM72" (в нотации языка C/C++ строка будет
>   выглядеть "\\.\COM72"). Такой синтаксис подходит для любого номера
>   порта. Точно так же они назывались в MS-DOS. Параллельные порты
>   называются «LPT1», «LPT2» и так далее.

А вот ссылка на источник:

https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/COM-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%B2_Windows_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: у меня открывало без слеша

Answer (score 1):

Поменял переходник на более хороший и все заработало как надо.
Всем спасибо за советы!